# Do I need a special videocard to use DVI-I to Dual VGA Female Connectors?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

Do I need a special video card to use a [DVI-I to Dual VGA splitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003V4TV9I), or will it work on pretty much anything 1GB and over?

Comment: Why would you need 1GB and over? If it is a mechanical splitter then it will work even with ancient 256 KB (yes, kilo) or less.

Comment: That's just what we have around here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work with any DVI-I connector, as it's just an analog line splitter.  You will end up with the computer only seeing one monitor, and the cable will split the signal to two VGA monitors (which of course, will display the same thing).

From [StarTech's website](http://ca.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/DVI-Cables/1-ft-DVI-I-Analog-to-2x-VGA-Video-Splitter-Cable-Male-to-Female~DVISPL1VV) under "Technical Specifications" (for the product you linked):

> This product will split your video signal to deliver two identical
>   images of the same resolution. *It cannot be used to span an image across two displays, or to show different images on each display*.

if that's what you want, then you should be good to go, otherwise, if you want different things on each display, you'll need to find a different solution (like perhaps [a USB DisplayLink adapter](http://www.displaylink.com/shop/adapters)).